# Верстка блоков выходящих за контейнер

Tags: html, css

Есть секция из двух колонок-левой и правой, элементы левой как бы находятся в контейнере, но одновременно с этим у нее должен быть бордер, от начала всей секции до соседнего блока с картой. Я сверстал с использованием абсолютов, но бордер у левой колонки так и не получилось реализовать.
Как сверстать такую секцию более правильно?

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.76, 37.64],
    zoom: 7
  });
  myMap.controls.remove('searchControl')
  myMap.controls.remove('trafficControl')
  myMap.controls.remove('fullscreenControl')
  myMap.controls.remove('rulerControl')
  myMap.controls.remove('typeSelector')
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
    max-width: 1700px;
  }

  .contacts__container {
    display: flex;
  }

  .contacts__content {
    position: relative;
  }

  .contacts__left-column {
    padding: 124px 122px 124px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #cacaca;
  }

  .contacts__left-column-heading {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 32px;
  }

  .contacts__form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 700px;
  }

  .contacts__map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 1239px;
    border-left: 1px solid #cacaca;

  }

  .contacts__address {
    margin-bottom: 27px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-style: normal;
  }

  [class*="-ground-pane"] {
    filter: grayscale(1);
  }

  .contacts__form-elem {
    margin-bottom: 23px;
  }

  .contacts__input {
    padding: 0 24px;
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    border-radius: 100px;
  }

  .contacts__form-btn {
    margin-bottom: 38px;
    align-self: flex-start;
    color: #cacaca;
  }
```

```html
<section class="contacts">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="subheading contacts__subheading">Заголовок секции</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="contacts__content">
      <div class="container contacts__container">
        <div class="contacts__left-column">
          <h3 class="text-reset contacts__left-column-heading font-bold">Заголовок</h3>
          <address class="contacts__address">Подзаголовок</address>
          <h3 class="contacts__left-column-heading">Другой подзаголовок</h3>
          <form class="contacts__form">
            <div class="contacts__form-elem">
              <input class="contacts__input" type="text" name="name" id="contacts__input-name" placeholder="Имя*">
              <label for="contacts__input-name"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="contacts__form-elem">
              <input class="contacts__input" type="tel" name="phone" id="contacts__input-phone" placeholder="Телефон*">
              <label for="contacts__input-phone"></label>
            </div>
            <button class="contacts__form-btn">Кнопка</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="contacts__map" id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

Comment: Перемудрили по-моему. Для `.contacts__map` уберите абсолютное позиционирование и вcякие top, right и bottom. У вас для этого блока указана ширина как 70%, ну и укажите для левой колонки ширину в 30%.

Comment: Ну так часть кода сократили, но бордер у левой колонки пока только до контейнера все равно

Comment: Читаю: "у нее должен быть бордер, от начала всей секции до соседнего блока с картой." Понимаю так, что до соседнего должен быть бордер, а у соседнего - нет. Если же верхняя рамка нужна и у блока с картой, кто мешает вам эту рамку там добавить?

Comment: Карте бордер не нужен, только блоку с формой) Кстати, так и не поняли меня видимо-карта должна тоже выходить за пределы контейнера, поэтому абсолют

Comment: Нет, я так и не понял, чего вы пытаетесь добиться.

Comment: нажмите "выполнить код", посмотрите в полноэкранном режиме и увидите, что у левого блока бордер упирается в контейнер, а нужно до конца секции

Comment: Смотрел я как работает ваш код. Секция занимает всю ширину. Левая колонка - 30%, карта - 70%. Если нужно, чтобы сверху была рамка на всю секцию, это означает, что рамку сверху необходимо сделать и у левой колонки, и у правой.

Comment: "Карте бордер не нужен, только блоку с формой". Не знаю, как еще объяснить, и почему вы отказываетесь понять, что всей секции бордер не нужен совершенно, что в секции есть контейнер, так как заголовки формы на одном уровне с заголовком секции

Comment: @Summersby что значит карта должна выходить за пределы контейнера? налазить сверху на форму или как?

Answer (score -1):

1. Понял так, что рамка сверху вам нужна только левой колонке с формой. Исходил из этого.
2. Рамку сверху сделал красным цветом для наглядности.
3. Опять же для наглядности, лишние стили не удалил, а только закомментировал.

Если запустить этот пример и открыть в полноэкранном режиме, можно убедиться, что рамка сверху у левой колонки с формой заканчивается строго перед картой и не наползает на неё. Это именно то, что вам нужно?

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.76, 37.64],
    zoom: 7
  });
  myMap.controls.remove('searchControl')
  myMap.controls.remove('trafficControl')
  myMap.controls.remove('fullscreenControl')
  myMap.controls.remove('rulerControl')
  myMap.controls.remove('typeSelector')
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
  //max-width: 1700px;
}

.contacts__container {
  display: flex;
}

.contacts__content {
  position: relative;
}

.contacts__left-column {
  padding: 124px 122px 124px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  width: 30%;
}

.contacts__left-column-heading {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.contacts__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  //max-width: 700px;
}

.contacts__map {
  //position: absolute;
  //top: 0;
  //right: 0;
  //bottom: 0;
  //width: 70%;
  //max-width: 1239px;
  border-left: 1px solid #cacaca;
}

.contacts__address {
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class*="-ground-pane"] {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.contacts__form-elem {
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}

.contacts__input {
  padding: 0 24px;
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.contacts__form-btn {
  margin-bottom: 38px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  color: #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<section class="contacts">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="subheading contacts__subheading">Заголовок секции</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="contacts__content">
      <div class="container contacts__container">
        <div class="contacts__left-column">
          <h3 class="text-reset contacts__left-column-heading font-bold">Заголовок</h3>
          <address class="contacts__address">Подзаголовок</address>
          <h3 class="contacts__left-column-heading">Другой подзаголовок</h3>
          <form class="contacts__form">
            <div class="contacts__form-elem">
              <input class="contacts__input" type="text" name="name" id="contacts__input-name" placeholder="Имя*">
              <label for="contacts__input-name"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="contacts__form-elem">
              <input class="contacts__input" type="tel" name="phone" id="contacts__input-phone" placeholder="Телефон*">
              <label for="contacts__input-phone"></label>
            </div>
            <button class="contacts__form-btn">Кнопка</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="contacts__map" id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

Comment: всё равно не могу понять, зачем карте левый бордер вместо правого у формы?

Comment: тут да, мой косяк, не удалил, это был один из экспериментов

Comment: Вот так должно выглядеть - https://c.radikal.ru/c27/2109/0d/c33a3bf9118f.jpg

Comment: Ответ никудышный-по макету ширина контейнера 1600, с учетом паддиногов 1700, а вы его удалили, так все просто у вас, я даже засмеялся, если бы так, я контейнер бы и не  делал вообще в секции, зафлексил бы два блока на 30 и 70 процентов, тут большого ума не надо